# Maclaurin series for the function: $f(z)=\frac{1}{2+4z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I want to find a Maclaurin series for the function: $$f(z)=\frac{1}{2+4z}$$ and to find its radius of convergence.

Now my attempt gave me:$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{(4z)^n(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}}\right)$$

which converges on $|z|\lt \frac12$

Can someone verify?

Comment: The results are perfectly correct but you can simplify a little. Just start with $$f(z)=\frac{1}{2+4z}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1+2z}$$ Another way could be to set $(4z)^n=4^n z^n=(2^2)^n z^n=2^{2n}z^n$ and simplify.

Comment: You are welcome !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the geometric series we get,
$$\frac 1{2+4z}=\frac12\frac1{1+2z}=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(2z)^n$$.

Your radius of convergence is correct.